# How to properly use random array on .apply() on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I quite understand the basic principle of using .apply() method on JS.

```js
function sayHi(x, y, z) {
  console.log("I'm " + this.name + ", My choices are" + x + "," + y + "," + z);
}
var personA = {
    name : "Albert"
};
var personB = {
    name : "Bob"
};

var name = "Cindy";
var options = [" a", " b", " c"];

sayHi.apply(personA, options); // "I'm Albert, My choices are a, b, c"
sayHi.apply(personB, [" d", " e", " f"]); // "I'm Bob, My choices are d, e, f"
```

Above snippet is an **ideal case** where you just want to use **certain amount** of array's element in `sayHi()` function and you pass on **the exact same amount** of data (array) needed for `sayHi()` function.

**However**, sometimes you need to utilize **all** of the array's element in given data set where the data could also be in **varying amount.** So instead of just accepting array with 3 elements, the `sayHi()` function can accept and array with 4,5, 6, or more elements, and not just accepting it but also utilizing all of the elements passed, something like this:

```
function sayHi(....) {
  // Accept any array with varying amount of elements, and using it
  for (...) {
    // A loop that will go through each element in given array
  }
}
var personA = {
    name : "Albert"
};
var personB = {
    name : "Bob"
};

var name = "Cindy";
var options3 = [" a", " b", " c"];
var options4 = [" a", " b", " c", " d"];
var options5 = [" a", " b", " c", " d", " e"];
// and so on

sayHi.apply(personA, options3);
sayHi.apply(personA, options4);
sayHi.apply(personA, options5);
```

and so far I haven't been able to find a way to do this, so I need your help to explain it to me.

Thanks,

Comment: You can pass in an object with name value pairs that are the properties to be created and their associated values. Then you can use *for..in* to iterate over the object's properties (or *Object.keys(params).forEach(...)*).

Comment: Old-school JS: use the `arguments` object. ES6 onwards: use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Comment: @nnnnnn—where "old school" means way more than half the browsers in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 3 different approaches.

**First, you could use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) array-like object instead of `x`, `y` and `z`.**

```
function sayHi() {
  for(var choice in arguments){
    // Do stuff.
  }
}
```

```js
function sayHi() {
  // Note that arguments is not an array but only an array-like object.
  var choicesStr = "My choices are " + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ", ");
  console.log("I'm " + this.name + ", " + choicesStr);
}
var personA = {
    name : "Albert"
};
var personB = {
    name : "Bob"
};

var name = "Cindy";
var options = ["a", "b", "c"];

sayHi.apply(personA, options); // "I'm Albert, My choices are a, b, c"
sayHi.apply(personB, ["d", "e", "f", "i", "j"]); // "I'm Bob, My choices are d, e, f"
```

The drawback of this approach is that `arguments` will contain every argument. If you need to provide a first argument that should be treated differently, you will have to extract it first.

**Second, you could make use of [ES6 rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) functionality.**

```
function sayHi(...choices) {
  for(var choice in choices){
    // Do stuff.
  }
}
```

```js
function sayHi(...choices) {
  // Note that unlike arguments, the rest parameter is a real array.
  var choicesStr = "My choices are " + choices.join(", ");
  console.log("I'm " + this.name + ", " + choicesStr);
}
var personA = {
    name : "Albert"
};
var personB = {
    name : "Bob"
};

var name = "Cindy";
var options = ["a", "b", "c"];

sayHi.apply(personA, options); // "I'm Albert, My choices are a, b, c"
sayHi.apply(personB, ["d", " e", " f", "i", "j"]); // "I'm Bob, My choices are d, e, f"
```

The advantage is that can easily provide heading parameters that will be considered separately.

```
function sayHi(firstArg, ...choices) {
  for(var choice in choices){
    // Do stuff.
  }
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that [its support is not yet widespread](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-rest_parameters). If this is a problem, you can use a transpiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io).

**Third, you could just pass an array with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) instead of [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)**

```js
function sayHi(choices) {
  var choicesStr = "My choices are " + choices.join(", ");
  console.log("I'm " + this.name + ", " + choicesStr);
}
var personA = {
    name : "Albert"
};
var personB = {
    name : "Bob"
};

var name = "Cindy";
var options = ["a", "b", "c"];

sayHi.call(personA, options); // "I'm Albert, My choices are a, b, c"
sayHi.call(personB, ["d", " e", "f", "i", "j"]); // "I'm Bob, My choices are d, e, f"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object of a function, which gives you an array of all arguments passed in, whether named or not.

```js
function sayHi(){  
  for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;++i){
    console.log( "Hi "+arguments[i] );  
  }
}

var parents = ["Mom","Dad"];
var children= ["Suzie","Jacob","Jerome","Sandra"];
sayHi.apply(this,parents);
sayHi.apply(this,children);
```

Note, however, that if you're going to pass an array of objects into a function, you can also, you know, just pass in the array, instead of jumping through `apply` and `arguments`:

```js
function sayHi(people){
  people.forEach(function(name){
    console.log( "Hi "+name );  
  });
}

var parents = ["Mom","Dad"];
var children= ["Suzie","Jacob","Jerome","Sandra"];
sayHi(parents);
sayHi(children);
```